# Unable to pass array to a Stored Procedure in DB2 - SQL PL - Windows

Tags: java, arrays, stored-procedures, db2

I am unable to call a stored procedure which has an input parameter as an integer array.

The stored procedure declaration is as follows

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTSCHEMA.TESTARRAY
      (IN CHECKSTATUS INTEGER,
      IN JOBID INTARRAY)
```

The array was declared like this

```
      CREATE TYPE INTARRAY AS INTEGER ARRAY[]@
```

When I try to call the procedure using

```
      CALL TESTSCHEMA.TESTARRAY( 1 , array[21,22,23] )@
```

I get the following error -

> An unexpected token "ARRAY[" was found following "ARRAY[".  Expected tokens may include: "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.63.123 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601'

I cannot seem to find any other way to do this? Can anyone please help with this?

Also need to find a way to pass the array in Java later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL PL arrays can only be used in SQL PL context. You'll need to declare a variable of the `INTARRAY` type and call your procedure, using that variable, from a compound SQL statement:

```
db2inst1@blusrv:~> db2 "create type INTARRAY AS INTEGER ARRAY[]"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2inst1@blusrv:~> db2 "create or replace procedure testarray(in checkstatus integer, in jobid intarray) begin call dbms_output.put_line('testarray'); end"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2inst1@blusrv:~> db2 set serveroutput on
DB20000I  The SET SERVEROUTPUT command completed successfully.
db2inst1@blusrv:~> db2 "begin declare v intarray; set v =  array[21,22,23]; call testarray(1,v); end"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

testarray
```